# Why is my variable not changing when modified in separate thread? c++/boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a vector of pointers (objects) that I pass into a thread using boost::ref, and in that thread I modify some variables of the objects. When I'm back in the main thread, the changes made in the thread are not applied and have their default values. I have debugged this and they do get changed in the thread, but in the main thread they haven't been changed. It's as if the boost::ref is not working and the parameters are being passed by value.

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
std::vector<Chunk *> chunks = divideScreen(width, height, chunkSize);

for (Chunk * chunk : chunks) {
    chunk->changed = 1; //initial value is 0, change it to 1 before passing to thread
    boost::thread chunkThread =  boost::thread(boost::bind(&Renderer::render, this, boost::ref(chunk)));
}

//wait for threads to finish


//back in main thread
std::cout << chunks[0]->changed << endl; //prints 1


void Renderer::render(Chunk * chunk) {
    chunk->changed = 2; //should be 2 - prints 2 in thread
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: btw it dont really understand why you think you need a reference to pointers, thats double indirection when a single one should suffice

Comment: I think that the problem might be in "wait for threads to finish". You should always call either `chunkThread.join()` or `chunkThread.detach()` on your thread. If my guess is not correct, please provide a full example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give the thread a reference to the `chunk` variable, which does no longer 'exist' after exiting the for loop.

So you may see the thread changing some value, but it really dereferences some stale `chunk` variable, uses the (unpredictable) content as a pointer, changes the memory location of what it thinks is the `changed` member.

You shouldn't give it a `ref`.  The thread needs the actual pointer, not the variable *holding* the pointer.

Comment: damn I'm good.  Avoid references when delegating work to other threads (same with lambda captures).